# Meteor authentication and react-router

Tags: authentication, meteor, reactjs, react-router

How do I get meteor to re-render my components when I sign in using the accounts-password package?

My react-router routes are:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import App from './containers/App'
import Recordings from './containers/Recordings'
import LandingPage from './containers/LandingPage'

import { BloodPressure } from '../collections/BloodPressure'

const routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={LandingPage} />
            <Route path="dashboard" component={Recordings} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
)

Meteor.startup( ()=> {
    ReactDOM.render(routes, document.querySelector('.render-target'))
})
```

My App component is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import Header from './Header'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="ui four container">
                    <Header />
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>

                <div className="footer">
                    <p>Designed and Developed by <a href="http://thomashoadley.co.uk" target="_blank">Thomas Hoadley</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>              
        )       
    }
}

export default createContainer(() => {
    return {
        signedIn: Meteor.userId()
    }
}, App)
```

When I sign in, I expect the page to automatically reload with the correct routes, however I am having to reload the page manually to redirect it.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!